# Are static methods ever safe in web development?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've used static "helper" methods & seen other people use them.  But are they ever safe in a multi-threaded environment like a web site?  Aren't  static methods always susceptible to multple threads entering at the same time and causing problems?

When do you use them?

Comment: That depends on what your code does. `public static int GiveMeANumber() { return 43; }` for instance will have no problems in multi threaded scenarios.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with multiple threads running the same method.  You need to be concerned about shared mutable state such as static fields.

Comment: Take a look at this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866407/are-static-methods-in-asp-net-code-behind-classes-non-thread-safe

Comment: It's per-class and per-executable *variables* that aren't safe.

Comment: FWIW: I've dropped all static classes (except for IoC setup) for DI singletons in the appropriate context. This is not inherently more/less safe than static classes (again, it's the mutable state which causes issues), but it sure makes dealing with contexts, dependencies, and testing easier.

Comment: Note that [thread safe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-safe) and [re-entrant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_%28subroutine%29) are different concepts. I think re-entrancy concerns are way more common/well know/easier to find/solve as it can be easily reproduced all the time in non-threaded environment (unlike  thread-safety that generally require proving in addition to trying code out).

Answer (score 7):

Yes, they can be very safe. There are plenty of examples in ASP.NET itself where there are static methods. [System.Web.HttpUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is an entire class that contains nothing but static methods (except the methods that it inherits from `System.Object`).

The biggest red flag to look for is static code that modifies a shared resource (such as a static property and/or field). You can perform such updates and code them safely, but whenever you see code that modifies a shared resource, it should cause you to pause and verify that it was done correctly.

Comment: t's any/all **static data** that you need to beware of (**static methods** are harmless): especially, any writing to or creation of static data.

Answer (score 4):

Yes they can be safe.

"Pure functions" that don't have side effects are an example.

Answer (score 4):

I use:

- Static startup and shutdown methods called from the `Application_Start` and `Application_End` methods in [Global.asax.cs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xaas8a2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

  - These methods are safer (single-threaded) than static constructors, for constructing static data
  - But beware of other static methods of Global, for example `Session_Start` and `Application_Error`, which may not be serialized.
- Static classes to define extension methods
- Static methods which have no side effects (which process their input parameters and return a result, without modifying global/static data)
- Static functions which are explicitly thread-safe e.g. because they use `lock` in their implementation

Comment: For point 3, if the input's state gets changed halfway through processing that could be a problem for the method.

Comment: The input parameters are typically owned by the thread which calls the static method.

Comment: Typically true, but it is something to be aware of.

Comment: @MrSmith It probably does: if the cache is global data which can be updated by multiple threads calling a static method, then access to that global data must be protected (e.g. using lock), or the global data must be implementing using e.g. one of the [thread-safe collection classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx).